# Use Cauchy's Multiplication Theorem and the Binomial Theorem to prove $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, exponential-function, exponential-sum

I am to use Cauchy's Multiplication Theorem and the Binomial Theorem in order to prove

$\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y) $

but I have no idea where to begin. All I can think of doing is setting $\exp(x)$ as the sum to infinity of $(x^n)/n!$ and similarly for $\exp(y)$, $(y^n)/n!$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ then by definition
\begin{equation}\exp(x)\exp(y)=(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!})(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^k}{k!})
\end{equation}
The Cauchy's Multiplication Theorem tells as that
\begin{equation}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kb_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k\end{equation}
when at least one of the two series of the RHS converge absolutely. In our case we have that \begin{equation}\exp(x)\exp(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\end{equation}
Now because $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$,
\begin{equation}\exp(x)\exp(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{y^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}\end{equation}
A straightforward application of the binomial theorem yields the resut:
\begin{equation}\exp(x)\exp(y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(x+y)^n=\exp(x+y)\end{equation}

Comment: If you could give me some hints and pointers, rather than posting the actual proof, that'd be great. I don't really understand why you're doing what you're doing at each step?

Comment: Sure I shall add more details if you would like!

Comment: That'd be really useful, thanks! Could you possibly explain where and how you've used Cauchy's multiplication theorem? That's the main part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I completely understand that now, thank you very much!

Comment: @Mathlete No problem. Have a good day